# How to check how much incomplete is a JPEG

Tags: python, imagemagick, jpeg, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

I was looking for a better technique to find a JPEG incomplete more flexible rather than the common technic which consist on search for the EOI byte at the end of the file. The idea is to not mark as incomplete image with a minimum percentile of the image data missed. However, seems this is not an easy thing.

The first idea was to try to detect which MCU are corrupted or missed, but giving the fact is compressed on a Huffman table, that is not easy job.

The other option I had was to calculate the content expected after the SOS Marker, and then if the real content does not much with the specified then I can calculate how much Image Data is missing.

Anybody can help me on this? I have tried several tools like ImageMagick or PIL (python) but I cannot fine a proper solution for that.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of this please? Who does it help if you know 29% of your JPEG is missing?

Comment: Exactly, that is the idea. Be able to calculate that 29% of the image is missed.

Comment: You would need to decode the image and hope it had restart markers.